# Changing label display in bokeh according to the text input

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a text input in my bokeh application as follows:

```
textbox=TextInput(value="DIAAAAC35TQSDA8", title="Enter deal_id:")
textbox.on_change("value", text_handler)
```

I use the text handler function to generate a new chart using:

```
source.data = dict(x=x_data, y=y_data)
```

This works perfectly fine. However, i also have a label in my original chart.

```
p.add_layout(Arrow(x_start=x_old, y_start=y_old, x_end=x_old, y_end=y_old, `end=VeeHead(fill_color="red", size=25)))
```

How do I make the x_old, y_old values change depending on the new textInput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a labelset and adding it to your plot.

`label = LabelSet(x='x',y='y',text='labels in ColumnDataSource', source=source)
 p.add_layout(labels)`

Then update it in your texthandler function by feeding it the new `ColumnDataSource` as source, assuming you handle your callback by updating a `ColumnDataSource`.

Comment: I used another label and different formats. But basically adding another source using ColumnDataSource worked. Thanks!